# Javascript array problem

Tags: javascript, arrays, parallel-processing

I have an array that i wish to looking into and only print something out when the array`==` another variable, however it seems to print out the statement whatever, am I missing something stupid?

```
var candArray = 
['Green...', 'Brown...', 'Black...', 'White...', 'Grey....','Blue....', 'Pink....'];

var votesArray= [33,51,43,22,61,51,47];
var maximumVote = 61;

for(i=0; i<candArray .length; i++){
if(votesArray[i] == maximumVote);{
 document.write(candArray [i] + ' is hearby declared elected');}
}
```

All help appreciated.
Thanks

EDIT: OMG i knew it was something simple, but ive been doing it so like 2 hours and just got into that phase where you dont check the simple things because you're too wound up. many thanks all

Comment: Is there also a space between candArray and .length in your actual code, or is that only from what you posted here?

Comment: You should ***really*** use `var i` so your loop variable doesn't become global.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `;` after the `if`.

An `if` statement affects the statement or block immediately after it.

You have an empty statement (`;`) after your `if`, so the subsequent block is not affected by the `if`.

Answer (score 2):

You had a semi-colon after your if condition...  It nullified your conditional, and then the code block that followed ran every time.

```
for(i=0; i < candArray.length; i++){
 if(votesArray[i] == maximumVote) {
   document.write(candArray [i] + ' is hearby declared elected');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `;` after the if statement:

```
var candArray = 
['Green...', 'Brown...', 'Black...', 'White...', 'Grey....','Blue....', 'Pink....'];

var votesArray= [33,51,43,22,61,51,47];
var maximumVote = 61;

for(i=0; i<candArray .length; i++){
if(votesArray[i] == maximumVote){ //<--remove the ;
 document.write(candArray [i] + ' is hearby declared elected');}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a semicolon after your 'if' statement that's messing it up.

Fixed:

```
var candArray = 
['Green...', 'Brown...', 'Black...', 'White...', 'Grey....','Blue....', 'Pink....'];

var votesArray= [33,51,43,22,61,51,47];
var maximumVote = 61;

for(i=0; i<candArray .length; i++){
if(votesArray[i] == maximumVote){
 document.write(candArray [i] + ' is hearby declared elected');}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a misplaced semicolon.

```
if(votesArray[i] == maximumVote);{
  document.write(candArray [i] + ' is hearby declared elected');}
}
```

should be:

```
if(votesArray[i] == maximumVote) {
  document.write(candArray [i] + ' is hearby declared elected');}
}
```